# Is there a way to turn a csv file of lat, long coordinates (originally township, range, section) into a polygon in QGIS without arc maps?

Tags: polygon, qgis

I am very inexperienced in QGIS and have only used it in class a handful of times. I have QGIS Desktop 3.8.2 and I am now working on an individual project for work. I have an Excel sheet of lat, long coordinates for 25 square sections. I am trying to create polygons for each township range section and make a color graded map with the number of roadkill deer found in each polygon. They are in the following format

Number of roadkill deer, Centroid Latitude, Centroid Longitude, NW Corner Latitude, NW Corner Longitude, NE Corner Latitude, NE Corner Longitude, SE Corner Latitude, SE Corner Longitude, SW Corner Latitude, SW Corner Longitude

If I input this it will only show one set of points, ie just the Centroid points. If I upload each corner as separate csv files they appear but I cannot get the point to path tool to work properly without zig-zagging

I have tried making a csv file with wkt format,
POLYGON((left lng bottom lat, left lng top lat, right lng top lat, right lng bottom lat, left lng bottom lat))
POLYGON((42.74065 -84.4426, 42.75523 -84.4623, 42.75526 -84.4424, 42.74073 -84.4426, 42.74065 -84.4624))
though the point appears in my layers docker window, there is no polygon on my map

Answer (score 0):

You may try other format. For example, with geojson you can easily visualize your data. You should provide crs code. Check [here](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-geojson.htm)